# open thymeleaf link in a new browser window

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I know that plenty of similar questions can be found here but none of them could help me with my problem.

What the client wants: click on a button, then open a new window with given parameters and show a view with dynamic data loaded from database.

What I have done so far:
I have a view with links, not buttons:

```
<a th:href="@{/report/reportPrintView(al=false, mlVersion=${report.version}, sv=true, id=${report.orderId})}" target="_blank">Protokoll</a>
<a th:href="@{/report/reportPrintView(al=true, mlVersion=${report.version}, sv=false, id=${report.orderId})}" target="_blank">Airline</a>
```

and a controller which is called by the GET request:

```
@GetMapping("/report/reportPrintView")
public String showReportPrint(@RequestParam("al") boolean al, @RequestParam("mlVersion") String mlVersion, @RequestParam("sv") boolean sv, @RequestParam("id") String id, Model model) {

    ........ do some magic .......

    return "/report/reportPrintView";
}
```

The view is displayed in a new browser tab and works as expected, but as said before, the client wants a new window.

To get a solution for the clients wishes I tried something like this:

```
function openWin(id, mlVersion, al, sv) {
    var url = "/report/reportPrintView.html?al=" + al + "&mlVersion=" + mlVersion + "&sv=" + sv + "&id=" + id;
    ReportPrintPreview = window.open("about:blank", "ReportPrintPreview", "width=666,height=700left=250,top=50,dependent=yes,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes");
    ReportPrintPreview.location.href = url;
    ReportPrintPreview.focus();
    return false;
}
.
.
.
<button th:onclick="'openWin(\'' + ${report.orderId} + '\', \'' + ${report.version} + '\', false, true)'">Protokoll</button>
<button th:onclick="'openWin(\'' + ${report.orderId} + '\', \'' + ${report.version} + '\', true, false)'">Airline</button>
```

What happens here is that a new window is opened with a 404 error and the web page with the button shows a 400 error. So I assume that the controller doesn't get the GET request and cannot show the view (as is a reasonable result because it's not a Thymeleaf call like @{/report/....}).
Is there any way to get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would structure that.

JavaScript

```
function openWin(url) {
    ReportPrintPreview = window.open("about:blank", "ReportPrintPreview", "width=666,height=700left=250,top=50,dependent=yes,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes");
    ReportPrintPreview.location.href = url;
    ReportPrintPreview.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Thymeleaf

```
<button
  th:data-url="@{/report/reportPrintView(al=false, mlVersion=${report.version}, sv=true, id=${report.orderId})}"
  onclick="openWin(this.getAttribute('data-url'))">Protokoll</button>

<button
  th:data-url="@{/report/reportPrintView(al=true, mlVersion=${report.version}, sv=false, id=${report.orderId})}"
  onclick="openWin(this.getAttribute('data-url'))">Airline</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not that you think I'm ignoring it but I cannot try this before tomorrow. I will give you feedback then

Comment: This, sir, solved my problem. Thank you very much. Short remark: the th:onclick call should look like this: th:onclick="'openWin(this.getAttribute(\'data-url\'))'" surrounding the openWin... with ' ' and escaping the 'data-url' ;)

Comment: @Raistlin -- if you notice, I used `onclick` instead of `th:onclick` because there is no need for thymeleaf to process that attribute.  You don't have to escape it in that case.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that hint. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

For thymeleaf it works in different way. try below.

```
th:target="_blank"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not that you think I'm ignoring it but I cannot try this before tomorrow. I will give you feedback then.

Comment: Since the client wants buttons instead of links I'd rather choose Metroids answer below as the accepted answer. But thank you anyway for your help.